# Название выхухоли

Tags: этимология

Многие смеются над названием этого зверя. Слово действительно забавное. Но какова его этимология?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очень мне нравится комментарий Фасмера: Выхухоль - "ондатра, мускусная крыса, Mygale moschata", диал. хохуля -- то же. **Темное слово**. Акад. Трубачев дает комментарий о возможном происхождении слова от калмыцкого ő xōxulu. В.И.Даль тоже ясности не добавляет: "Хохуля, а оттоль выхухоль, вонючий, пахучий; или от хахаль, волокита, смешной щеголь, раздушеный**?**"

Интересно, что слово **выхухоль** в современном русском языке относится к двуродовым, то есть оно может склоняться и как существительное женского рода (как моль), и как существительное мужского рода (как тюль). У Высоцкого выхухоль женского рода: *«Царь дарует вам шубу с плеча из естественной выхухоли»*, у Аксенова выхухоль мужского рода: *«…джинсы с выпушками из меха выхухоля»*. Еще пример: *Центр охраны дикой природы проводил акцию «Сохраним русскую выхухоль!».*